# What's an intuitive way to check if a number contains two consecutive 0s in it's binary representation?

Tags: java, algorithm, bit-manipulation

So, If I want to check that a number contains two consecutive 1s, I can simply do `(n & (n >>> 1)) == 0` 
 I'm thinking that to check if the number contains two consecutive 0's you would do the same thing but just inverting the bits: `(~n & (~n >>> 1)) == 0`. However, this doesn't seem to produce the correct result. It does make sense, logically, invert the bits and apply the same principle to check if two consecutive 1s are next to each other. Is there a more efficient and/ or intuitive way to do this?

Comment: I was wondering about the order of operations for `~n >>> 1`, and wonder if that's affecting your results.

Comment: Do you mean `(n & (n >> 1)) == 0` instead of `(n & (n >>> 1)) == 0`?

Comment: Wouldn't you have to invert the outermost expression? `~(~n & (~n >>> 1)) == 0`, or equally, `(~n & (~n >>> 1)) == 0xFF...FF`

Comment: @Stef In Java, `>>>` is an unsigned right shift. I didn't really think that would make a different to do it either with `>>` or `>>>`? Or does it?

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica Why `0XFF...FF` ?

Comment: @MutatingAlgorithm Oops, my bad, I didn't realise this was Java and I didn't know this Java operator.

Comment: I think you need a language tag for your question. Otherwise, you cause confusion.

Comment: Every number contains an infinite number of consecutive 0s in its binary representation (the leading zeros). You need to ask a more specific question. Do you want consecutive zeros in the first K bits, or consecutive non-leading zeros?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. consecutive zeros after the most significant bit

Answer (score 2):

*If and only if* `n` has no consecutive zeros after the first 1, the next statement makes `n` one less than a power of 2:

```
n |= n >>> 1
```

*If and only if* `n` is one less than a power of 2, the next statement makes `n` equal to zero:

```
n &= n + 1
```